# SharePoint 2013 Blog: sort posts by authors

Tags: sorting, xslt, sharepoint, filter, blogs

I'm trying to make a custom filter which sorts on authors (users) in the SharePoint 2013 blog. I'm working with XSL dataview and it's exported to a web part. I have a column called Author which gets the information from Created By. When I click on a user in the web part it shows all posts instead of the selected author. The URL is mysite/default.aspx?Author=FirstName LastName".

Code (default.aspx):

```
 <xsl:template match="/" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls">
    <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="dvt_1">
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_StyleName">RepForm3</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[not(@Author.title=preceding-sibling::Row/@Author.title)]" />

    <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.header">
        <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows" />
    </xsl:call-template>

    <div class="blogRefineByAuthorContainer">
        <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.body">
            <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="dvt_1.header">
        <xsl:param name="Rows" />
        <div class="blogRefineByAuthorEveryAuthor"><a href="default.aspx">Everyone</a></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="dvt_1.body">
        <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
            <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.rowview" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="dvt_1.rowview">
        <div class="blogRefineByAuthorAuthorTitle">
            <a href="default.aspx?Author={@Author.title}"><xsl:value-of select="@Author.title" /></a>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
```

Any ideas of what it could be? Between the first and last name there is a space in the URL, but I don't think it makes any sense. I have tried with %20 without any result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why my xpath doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25470535/why-my-xpath-doesnt-work)